# jqGrid not reloading/refreshing on ajax post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I have a ajax post request and on success I am calling jqgrid to populate the data. On the first request I am getting right data on my grid but when I choose some filter(search options) and hit search button again the grid is not reloading , its displaying same old data. I tested using  alert and alert is getting right data its just that grid is not reloading to display new data. I spent all day and applied too many reload option suggested by other people but non worked. It's been 2 days I could not figure out this issue. I am still stuck any help please.

```js
var a = $("name").val;

$.ajax({

    url: 'someurl',
    type: 'post',
    data: a,
    cache:false,
    contentType:false,
    dataType:false,
    processData: false,
    
    sucess: function(response){
    
        alert(response);
        test(response);
        $("#divval").jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype: 'json', data:response}).trigger("reloadGrid");
    }

});

//grid
function test(data){
  datatype:"jsonstring",
  datastr:response,
  jsonReader:{
    repeatitiveitems:false,
    ...
    ..
  },
  colNames:[],
  colModel:[],
  loadonce:true,
  ...
  ...


}
```

```html
<div id="divval"></div>
```